# Как работает онлайн игра на сайте клавагонки?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток! Давно интересовал вопрос онлайн режимов на сайтах, ведь основная проблема веб страниц заключается в том, что клиент через браузер по http протоколу посылает запрос на сервер, а сервер получая этот запрос возвращает ответ. И такой односторонний обмен, где пользователю нужно самостоятельно отправлять запросы,  происходил до тех пор пока разработчики не внедрили технологию Ajax. Одним из хороших примеров использования этой технологии является сайт [клавогонки](http://klavogonki.ru) Внимание вопрос! Может ли кто-нибудь из вас привести пример кода в котором будет возможность хотя-бы двум пользователям одновременно набирать один и тот же текст в онлайн режиме? Или если есть примеры похожих скриптов, CMS моделей?

Comment: А подсмотреть на самом сайте клавогонки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Технология то достаточно проста - вы посылаете запрос - сервер его обрабатывает, отправляет ответ. Ajax - это только один из способов асинхронной отправки запроса и последующей его обработки в рамках веб страницы. Если применительно с jquery то Вам надо наверное для начала почитать про [это](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Хотите код? Можно такой:

```
...
$.ajax({url:"request.php", data:{user_id:some_user_id}, dataType:"script"});
...
```

в ответ сервер должен вернуть js код для выполнения в браузере клиента.

Соответственно серверный скрипт должен на основе входного user_id идентифицировать пользователя, выполнить все нужные действия и вернуть адекватный ответ.

В применении к приведённому Вам сайту, механизм там скорее всего такой:
Текст у них один, анализ его ввода проверяется js ом на клиенте(браузере) (js знает весь текст). А по успешным, не успешным, или по таймеру серверу отправляется статистика о вводе, текущем слове и т.д. и в ответ сервер отправляет состояние оппонента.

Вообще почитайте ещё о клиент-серверных технологиях.

Comment: Хороший ответ, но нельзя ли побольше кода с примерами. Самым интересным моментом на том сайте является возможность одновременно печатать один и тот же текст. Как это происходит? Неужели при каждом нажатии на клавишу идет обмен с сервером?

Comment: В данном случае я думаю обмен идёт не на каждое нажатие а на каждое правильно введённое слово.